# Wacom DTF521 mapped to my Laptop Monitor

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, ubuntu-gnome, wacom

Bought a laptop, installed Ubuntu Gnome, Latest Nvidia drivers plugged my Wacom DTF521, calibrated but come down to one problem

-first, my wacom misclicked every time i lifted the pencil, to avoid this i haved to swap over the sides or lift it really fast.

-then, after a disconection and reconection, nowit seems my tablet is mapped to the laptop monitor, everything is plugged as before and i didnt changed any settings, i dont know why!!?

can someone help me solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
xsetwacom set <device> MapToOutput <monitor name>
```

please see:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Dual_and_Multi-Monitor_Set_Up

Comment: yes i did read this, at the end it seems like xsetwacom "Device name" MapToOutPut HEAD-1 did the trick, but when i open calibration settings, it still displays the calibration app in the laptop monitor, also dis doesnt survive reboots

Delete whole gnome settings, discovered that problem happens when the VGA cable is disconected, BUT the USb cable is still on and tablet is On, this makes it work as a regular non-screen tablet on the monitor, when VGA is plugged back, keeps in Main monitor

Comment: Link has moved https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Dual-and-Multi-Monitor-Set-Up